# I want to display different prices for logged in (wholesale) and logged out (retail) customers in woocommerce website

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing the e-commerce website, I want to display the different price for loggedin users and different for loggedout users. Can anyone please let me know how can I do this in woocommerce.

Comment: try this plugin, fits what you have described: http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-wholesale-prices/5325378

Answer (score 0):

You will need some custom code. This gets placed in your theme `functions.php` file or custom plugin code.

```
function custom_get_price( $price, $product  ) {
    $discount = 0.5;
    if( is_user_logged_in() )
        $price = $price * $discount;

    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'custom_get_price',10,2);
```

This code hooks into the WooCommerce `get_price()` function in the `abstract-wc-product.php` file.

Some resources on adding custom code to WordPress

- https://www.woothemes.com/2014/09/properly-add-woocommerce-custom-code/
- https://dev7studios.com/adding-code-customisations-wordpress-the-right-way/
- https://docs.woothemes.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/

Comment: Lot of thanks @James Jones. I just want to confirm from you that will it works with my requirement? Actually I am newbie in this thing so if you will explain me about this thing then it would be beneficial for me.

Comment: @manu I can't teach you how to code from scratch. If you have specific questions we can answer them.

Comment: Thanks @James. I will try to do it from my end. Will see you again if I stuck in some issue.

Comment: @manu I added some links to tutorials that may help. Also welcome to stack overflow. If you find the answer useful please upvote it. If it solves your question please mark it as resolved